# MariaDB 10.2 / MySQL 5.7 Remove Text in a field using a wildcard?

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, mariadb, wildcard

I have a description field and I want to remove all occurences of some text in the description that match. Note that 81/29 will always be different numbers. sometimes they may be more digits such as 2-4 in length.

Sample data:

```
To support this group, visit: https://example.com/give/81/29 The normal description continues here. There will be a lot of text below....
```

After Query:

```
The normal description continues here. There will be a lot of text below....
```

Is there a way to search and replace with a wildcard?

For example:

```
UPDATE articles 
SET description = REPLACE(description, 'To support this group, visit: https://example.com/give/%/% ', '');
```

This doesn't work obviously. Does Replace have any wildcard or RegEX function?

Answer (score 0):

With string functions `LOCATE()` and `INSTR()`:

```
UPDATE articles 
SET description = SUBSTRING(
  description, 
  LOCATE(' ', description, INSTR(description, 'https')) + 1
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cUTJsQyuK9HJrTL1zGn3k6/0).

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to extract the excerpt **starting from** the **last digit without the leading space**. So use :

```
UPDATE articles 
   SET description=LTRIM(
                         SUBSTRING( description, 
                                  - REGEXP_INSTR( REVERSE( description ) , '[0-9]' ) + 1 )
                   )
```

where to determine

**starting from** *-->* `SUBSTRING()`

**last**  *-->* `REVERSE()`

**digit** *-->* `REGEXP_INSTR()`

**without the leading space** *-->* `LTRIM()`

functions are used.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=32ac0530074df28e41f5bdd6de3a96ad)</kbd>